# How do we solve the equations from Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: analysis, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

How can we solve the following system?
\begin{align*}&y-3x^2y-y^3+2\lambda x=0 \\ & x-x^3-3xy^2+2\lambda y  =0 \\ &  x^2+y^2-1=0 \end{align*}
I have done the following:

Multiply the first equation by $y$ and the second by $x$ :
\begin{align*}&y^2-3x^2y^2-y^4+2\lambda xy=0 \\ & x^2-x^4-3x^2y^2+2\lambda xy  =0 \\ &  x^2+y^2-1=0 \end{align*}
Second equation minus first equation :
\begin{align*}&y^2-3x^2y^2-y^4+2\lambda xy=0 \\ & x^2-x^4-y^2+y^4  =0 \\ &  x^2+y^2-1=0 \end{align*}
From last equation we solve for $x^2$ :
\begin{align*}&y^2-3x^2y^2-y^4+2\lambda xy=0 \\ & x^2-x^4-y^2+y^4  =0 \\ &  x^2=1-y^2\end{align*}
Substitute in the first equation the term $x^2$ :
\begin{align*}&y^2-3x^2y^2-y^4+2\lambda xy=0 \\ & 1-y^2-(1-y^2)^2-y^2+y^4  =0 \\ &  x^2=1-y^2\end{align*}
The second equation is a trivial one, right?

What else could we do to find the solutions?

Comment: Are you sure that $\lambda$ is the same in the two equations?

Comment: Independently of that, with the use of $x^2+y^2=1$  at the right beginning, the two first equations simplify to $-2xy^2+2\lambda y=0$ and $-2x^2y+2\lambda x=0.$

Comment: Adding two first equations leads to $(x+y)(xy-\lambda) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)